# Search in a Binary Search Tree(Leetcode)

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

You are given the root of a binary search tree (BST) and an integer val.

Find the node in the BST that the node's value equals val and return the subtree rooted with that node. If such a node does not exist, return null.

Why 'ans=root' is not working??

```
class Solution {
public:
    void searchBSTHelper(TreeNode* root, int val, TreeNode* ans){
        //Base case
        if(root == NULL){
            ans = ans;
            return;
        }
        
        if(val > root->val){
            searchBSTHelper(root->right,val,ans);
        }
        else if(val < root->val){
             searchBSTHelper(root->left,val,ans);
        }
        else if(val == root->val){
            ans = root;
            cout<<ans->val<<" "<<ans->left->val<<" ";
            return;
        }
    }
    TreeNode* searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
        TreeNode * ans = NULL;
        searchBSTHelper(root,val,ans);
        //cout<<ans->val<<" ";
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to reassign a pointer inside a function, you should pass it by reference, i.e.

```cpp
searchBSTHelper(TreeNode* root, int val, TreeNode*& ans)
```

You're not getting the desired output as you're passing the `ans` pointer by value instead.

Btw, what's the point of `ans = ans`? You can just return if the node is null.

You don't really need the helper function altogether, you can just use the given `searchBST` function for recursion.